# How can I prevent the error "Invalid JSON response" with dataTables in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, json, symfony, error-handling, datatables

I created a DataTable with symfony:

src/Entity/User.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=191, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
     */
    private $isActive;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
        // may not be needed, see section on salt below
        // $this->salt = md5(uniqid('', true));
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // you *may* need a real salt depending on your encoder
        // see section on salt below
        return null;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
            $this->id,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            // see section on salt below
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
    }
}
```

templates/homepage.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Symfony{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div class="wrapper">

{{ include('inc/navbar.html.twig') }}

<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 866px;">

  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">

        <div class="box">
          <!-- /.box-header -->
          <div class="box-body">

            <table id="users">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>ID</th>
                          <th>Username</th>
                          <th>email</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
              </table>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<!-- /.content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

{% endblock %}
```

src/DataTables/UsersDataTable.php

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use DataTables\DataTableHandlerInterface;
use DataTables\DataTableQuery;
use DataTables\DataTableResults;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class UsersDataTable implements DataTableHandlerInterface
{
    protected $doctrine;

    /**
     * Dependency Injection constructor.
     *
     * @param RegistryInterface $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function handle(DataTableQuery $request): DataTableResults
    {
        /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $repository */
        $repository = $this->doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:User');

        $results = new DataTableResults();

        // Total number of users.
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')->select('COUNT(u.id)');
        $results->recordsTotal = $query->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

        // Query to get requested entities.
        $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u');

        // Search.
        if ($request->search->value) {
            $query->where('(LOWER(u.username) LIKE :search OR' .
                          ' LOWER(u.email) LIKE :search)');
            $query->setParameter('search', strtolower("%{$request->search->value}%"));
        }

        // Filter by columns.
        foreach ($request->columns as $column) {
            if ($column->search->value) {
                $value = strtolower($column->search->value);

                // "ID" column
                if ($column->data == 0) {
                    $query->andWhere('u.id = :id');
                    $query->setParameter('id', intval($value));
                }
                // "Username" column
                elseif ($column->data == 1) {
                    $query->andWhere('LOWER(u.username) LIKE :username');
                    $query->setParameter('username', "%{$value}%");
                }
                // "Email" column
                elseif ($column->data == 2) {
                    $query->andWhere('LOWER(u.email) LIKE :email');
                    $query->setParameter('email', "%{$value}%");
                }
            }
        }

        // Order.
        foreach ($request->order as $order) {

            // "ID" column
            if ($order->column == 0) {
                $query->addOrderBy('u.id', $order->dir);
            }
            // "Username" column
            elseif ($order->column == 1) {
                $query->addOrderBy('u.username', $order->dir);
            }
            // "Email" column
            elseif ($order->column == 2) {
                $query->addOrderBy('u.email', $order->dir);
            }
        }

        // Get filtered count.
        $queryCount = clone $query;
        $queryCount->select('COUNT(u.id)');
        $results->recordsFiltered = $queryCount->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

        // Restrict results.
        $query->setMaxResults($request->length);
        $query->setFirstResult($request->start);

        /** @var \AppBundle\Entity\User[] $users */
        $users = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $results->data[] = [
                $user->getId(),
                $user->getUsername(),
                $user->getEmail(),
            ];
        }

        return $results;
    }
}
```

src/Controller/DataTableController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use DataTables\DataTablesInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
*
* @Route("/users", name="users")
*
* @param Request $request
* @param DataTablesInterface $datatables
* @return JsonResponse
*/

class DataTableController extends Controller
{

  const ID = 'users';

  public function usersAction(Request $request, DataTablesInterface $datatables): JsonResponse
  {
    try {
      // Tell the DataTables service to process the request,
      // specifying ID of the required handler.
      $results = $datatables->handle($request, 'users');

      return $this->json($results);
    }
    catch (HttpException $e) {
      // In fact the line below returns 400 HTTP status code.
      // The message contains the error description.
      return $this->json($e->getMessage(), $e->getStatusCode());
    }
  }

}
```

But I get the error message:

> DataTables warning: table id=users - Invalid JSON response.

I did a network analyse, but there everything seems to work fine:

[image]

Comment: Check response body, not network.

Comment: @u_mulder What does this mean exactly?

Comment: This means that you should open `console` tab, find request to server and check its response.

Comment: Ok, here is the result: https://i.imgur.com/oWacL2X.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your request type is GET so you can paste you request url directly to browser and you will see if response is valid JSON. Invalid JSON response means that result of your request is not JSON, maybe you have false or error.

Comment: I do not know what is the request url

Comment: `* @Route("/users", name="users")` from your code i guess it will be something like yourdomain/users.